# Hacked WordPress site and added JS code - atob("...")

Tags: javascript, wordpress, security

I have a WordPress site with one admin account.

At some point, I discovered a plugin that I did not install.
The plugin is called - "WPCode Lite".
With it, JS code was added to all pages of the site:

```
<script>document.write(atob("PHN...[LOTS OF ENCRYPTED TEXT]...cHQ+"));</script>
```

This code hung on the site for about a week until I noticed it.

Most likely, the hacker picked up the password from the administrator account.
I changed my password to something even more complex.

Questions:
What does this code do?
What are the consequences?

Comment: Something nasty. More than that would require the uncensored code involved. It might redirect users off-site, it might run cryptocurrency mining in the browser, who knows?

Comment: Open up a browser console and paste in `atob("whatever that text is")`. You'll see whatever it's adding to your html documents. Careful. Do this in an incognito window, and if possible on a sacrificial VM. And, if you can restore your site from a backup taken before the cybercreep got in, that will be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.write replaces the html document with the given input.

The atob function decodes a base64 string.

From the looks of it this long encoded string contains the actual code being decrypted by atob.

EDIT

Since OP shared the full string :
This is heavily obfuscated javascript looks like it's fetching something from some other URL and running an eval on the result.

This means this is a backdoor that fetches the real malware from another server.

PS:
**You probably shouldn't be sharing potential malware on stackoverflow**.